# LetsEncrypt certbot timeout error when the url works

Tags: nginx, lets-encrypt

I'm using it with nginx. Testing with a file in `.well-known/acme-challenge` works fine (see [this link on the domain](https://www.devpy.me/.well-known/acme-challenge/test.txt)), and the files are created. Here is the error:

```
$ certbot certonly --webroot -w /var/www/ghost -d devpy.me -d www.devpy.me -d

grunt.devpy.me
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
Cert is due for renewal, auto-renewing...
Renewing an existing certificate
Performing the following challenges:
http-01 challenge for devpy.me
http-01 challenge for www.devpy.me
http-01 challenge for grunt.devpy.me
Using the webroot path /var/www/ghost for all unmatched domains.
Waiting for verification...
Cleaning up challenges
Unable to clean up challenge directory /var/www/ghost/.well-known/acme-challenge
Failed authorization procedure. grunt.devpy.me (http-01): urn:acme:error:connection :: The server could not connect to the client to verify the domain :: Fetching https://www.devpy.me/.well-known/acme-challenge/dOG2V7ugcr6OHkQZGNBs-hmS0c7QQh0dZfCKcfLejpc: Timeout, www.devpy.me (http-01): urn:acme:error:connection :: The server could not connect to the client to verify the domain :: Fetching http://www.devpy.me/.well-known/acme-challenge/JLQ33HESAhFMGSP0GdIFXt9RbJISSfrUdcFSbySRSlA: Timeout, devpy.me (http-01): urn:acme:error:connection :: The server could not connect to the client to verify the domain :: Fetching http://devpy.me/.well-known/acme-challenge/FR0pZ17-lOUMvQqX1nDNWE2WlOp7g0uMDvrwXYZlwEs: Timeout

IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - The following errors were reported by the server:

   Domain: grunt.devpy.me
   Type:   connection
   Detail: Fetching
   https://www.devpy.me/.well-known/acme-challenge/dOG2V7ugcr6OHkQZGNBs-hmS0c7QQh0dZfCKcfLejpc:
   Timeout

   Domain: www.devpy.me
   Type:   connection
   Detail: Fetching
   http://www.devpy.me/.well-known/acme-challenge/JLQ33HESAhFMGSP0GdIFXt9RbJISSfrUdcFSbySRSlA:
   Timeout

   Domain: devpy.me
   Type:   connection
   Detail: Fetching
   http://devpy.me/.well-known/acme-challenge/FR0pZ17-lOUMvQqX1nDNWE2WlOp7g0uMDvrwXYZlwEs:
   Timeout

   To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
   entered correctly and the DNS A/AAAA record(s) for that domain
   contain(s) the right IP address. Additionally, please check that
   your computer has a publicly routable IP address and that no
   firewalls are preventing the server from communicating with the
   client. If you're using the webroot plugin, you should also verify
   that you are serving files from the webroot path you provided.
```

The grunt.devpy.me and devpy.me are redirected to www.devpy.me. Trying to renew gives the same issue.

Comment: You ever figure this out? Having the exact same issue.

Comment: Yeah I think I temporarily just turned off the server and hosted just the webcert. Something was interfering.

Comment: Temporarily turned off the server? As in you just did a reboot? So far that's one thing I haven't tried yet. I'm pulling my hair out trying to get this thing to validate. I've done others before in the past and haven't had this trouble.

Comment: if you're self-hosting the site, check that the http URL actually works outside your network. my issue ended up being that my ISP blocks port 80, so certbot always failed. once they opened it, problem solved.